Deriving constant-acceleration kinematic equations without calculus
When I go back and read my freshman physics textbook (University Physics - Young & Freedman) and others like it that I’ve attained since (Fundamentals of Physics - Halliday & Resnick) they all derive the kinematic equations the same way without calculus — at least at first.
Namely, they consider the case of constant acceleration (and non-constant acceleration separately) and start with the definition of average acceleration, over a time interval $[t_1,t_2]$: $$a_{\text{av}-x}=\frac{v_{2x}-v_{1x}}{t_2-t_2}$$ where $v_{2x}$ is the instantaneous velocity at time $t_2$ and $v_{1x}$ is the instantaneous velocity at time $t_1.$ Let $t_1=0$ and $t_2=t$ be any time after $0$, and $v_{2x}=v_x$ and $v_{1x}=v_{0x}$. Now importantly, since the acceleration is constant, the average acceleration over any interval $a_{\text{av}-x}$ equals the instantaneous acceleration $a_x$ at any point on that interval. Therefore $$a_{\text{av}-x}=a_x=\frac{v_x-v_{0x}}{t}\implies v_x= v_{0x}+a_xt.$$
This is just a restatement of the definitions though. Next comes the equation from which everything follows, yet it is always asserted without proof in these texts: $$v_{\text{av}-x}= \frac{1}{2}(v_{0x}+v_x), $$
asserting that the average velocity over $[t_1, t_2]$ is given by the average of the (instantaneous) $x$-velocities at the beginning and end of the interval. Then $$\frac{x-x_0}{t}= v_{\text{av}-x}= \frac{1}{2}(v_{0x}+\left(v_{0x}+a_xt\right)) \implies \Delta x = v_{0x}t+\frac{1}{2}a_xt^2,$$ from which the other kinematic equations follow.
The issue I have here logically is that there appears to be no way to derive or prove that $v_{\text{av}-x}= \frac{1}{2}(v_{0x}+v_x)$ without resorting directly to integrals or to area under linear velocity graphs (why does total area give total displacement?), which is again calculus in disguise.
There of course is the hand-wavy argument that the average velocity is simply the average of the $x$-velocities at the beginning and end of the interval, but this is relying on the everyday interpretation of ‘average’ in ‘average velocity’ instead of using its definition.
So is there no way to rigorously justify constant acceleration kinematics without calculus?

I agree with your assessment that establishing that the average velocity (as in, the standard average of initial and final velocities) is equal to the average velocity (as in the time-average) for constant-acceleration motion requires calculus.

why is there a subscript "x"? It just makes reading the notion more confusing. If this is a 1D problem, then please restate w/o a coordinate (x). Also, if the velocity is a function of time, then use $v(t)$ generally, and $v(t_1)$ and $v(t_2)$ for the endpoints; however, "$i$=initial and $f$=final is preferable.

@JEB I’m following the notation in University Physics by Young & Freedman, where they’re discussing $1$D horizontal motion. They just use $v_x$ for instantaneous velocity at a point or as a function of time both without $t$, and $v$ for speed. I agree the $x$-coordinate is slightly redundant though in $1$D.

I may be off the mark here, but since it seems that you do accept the derivation given for the formula relating the final speed $v(t)$ and the initial speed $v(0)$ given a constant acceleration $a$ during time $t$:
$$ v(t) = v(0) + at, \tag{1}$$
then note that we have:
$$ v(t/2) = v(0) + \frac12 at, \tag{2}$$
from which we can easily get:
\begin{align*}
v(t/2) &= \frac{2v(0) + at}{2} 
\\&= \frac{v(0)+v(0)+at}{2} 
\\&= \frac{v(0)+v(t)}{2} & \text{via (1)}
\\&= v_{\text{avg}}
\end{align*}
So that we can use $(1)$ alone to demonstrate that the speed attained at $t/2$ or $t=\frac12(t_1+t_2)$ in your initial definitions, is exactly the average of the initial and final speeds.
Now of course, you can question whether under uniform acceleration it is indeed correct that it's at $t/2$ when average speed is attained. But I think that's no more "handwavy" than claiming, for example, that a body moving with uniform speed for some time $t$ has covered precisely half of its final displacement at time $t/2$.
In other words, I think that physically there's no reason to think speed should be different than displacement in this regard, because the relation of speed to uniform acceleration is exactly analogous to the relation between displacement and a given uniform speed (a linear relation).
So, since the argument about the average displacement is something that we do normally also accept without proof in the very early stages of studying kinematics, I think there's no need to require calculus to prove the analogue for the average speed, i.e., that it is attained also at $t/2$ under uniform acceleration.

The issue I have is with the definitions. Why should $v_{\text{avg}}=v(t/2)?$ In this case, $v_{\text{avg}}$ is defined as $\frac{x-x_0}{t-t_0}=\frac{x-x_0}{t}$

@NoSingularities well, if I ask you how you define average displacement, given an initial displacement $x_0$ and the final displacement $x$, you'll probably agree a reasonable definition is $(x+x_0)/2$, right? but $x(t)=x_0+vt$ under the assumption of constant speed. So we get the average displacement as $$\bar{x} = \frac{x_0+x_0+vt}{2} = \frac{x_0+x}{2}.  $$ which you can check is $x(t/2)$. I am basically saying the same argument applies to the average speed.

Why would you want to avoid calculus concepts? That seems like a bad idea. I can understand avoiding calculus computations, but not the concepts.

When you say it’s just as handwavy to say $d=rt,$ well we define average velocity to be $v_{\text{av}-x}=(x_2-x_1)/(t_2-t_1)$ so if we’re talking about displacement then letting $x_2=x, x_1=0, t_2=t,$ and $t_1=0$ we get $v_{\text{av}-x}=x/t$ or $x = v_{\text{av}-x}t$. But if the velocity (or speed, in this case) is uniform then the average rate of change of position with respect to time is constant and equal to the instantaneous rate of change of position, or velocity $v_x=v,$ on that interval. So $x=v_{\text{av}-x}t=v_xt=vt.$ No calculus required.

In your example, I would say that (displacement) position is a function of $t$, and that the only “average” I know for functions is the calculus one $\frac{1}{t}\int_0^t x(t) dt $ over an interval. The average velocity is not a function of $t$, it is a function of an interval $[t_0, t_1].$ I think what you’re saying is that the average value of a linear function is the midpoint of the y-values or the output at the midpoint of the inputs. I’m just saying I’m not sure how “average value of a function” relates to $v_{\text{av}-x}$ given how it’s defined.

@NoSingularities Okay, it wasn't initially clear from your question that your point of departure is taking $v_{\text{avg}} = (x-x_0)/$ as the defining equation for $v_{\text{avg}}$. I understand the issue better now. I think that in this case, it can be perfectly reasonable to provide a geometrical proof, it's completely rigorous plane Euclidean geometry to show that the area under $v(t)=v(0)+at$ is equal the area under the constant function $\bar{v}(t) = v_{\text{avg}}$ between $t=0$ and $t$. The only remaining doubt may be why is that area the displacement...

but you can address that one several ways: 1. Note the dimensional consistency, the $x$ axis of the function has units of time and the $y$ axis has units of speed, so that the area indeed has units of length so dimensionally consistent with displacement. 2. You can start by showing that it is indeed the generated displacement from the case of a uniform velocity, which is easier to grasp. Then add up several discrete sections of uniform velocity, etc. until you convince the student that it also works for a linearly changing velocity.

.. finally I must point out that I agree with Dale.. avoiding calculus shouldn't be a goal unto itself. Since any student of physics is going to have to study calculus at some point, it is arguably better to use the words "this is only rigorously justified by using calculus", than find the 0.001% of the cases where we can do it without calculus. If the student won't continue with physics in the future, it won't matter, and if he does, he's gonna need a lot of calculus anyway. In physics we sometimes like to describe things in a "coordinate free" way... but calculus free? No way! :)

I’m going to have to disagree with your answer here (the other answers also have some handwavyness hidden in their paragraphs). Avoiding calculus for the sake of it is of course a terrible goal, but this is an interesting question and @NoSingularities is right and the honest answer to OP’s question is “no, there’s no way to do this rigorously without calculus in full”. Pretty much everything at the pre-FTC level requires some amount of trust in the hand-waving process. Fortunately, these handwaving tactics are believable.

@peek-a-boo well as I said above, in writing this answer I didn't correctly understand what OP wants to take as the definition of average speed. After I understood the matter, I already agreed that justifying that definition is best done via calculus.. what I mentioned about the geometrical "proof" is indeed probably at best a motivation for requiring calculus here, rather than really a substitute for it.

@peek-a-boo Note that in general, this question can be summed up as "Is it possible to prove without calculus that the area under the speed graph is equal the displacement traversed?". That's really the only crux of the matter, but I think it was somewhat obscured in more peripheral definitions that OP chose to focus on. If that was made clear, I would also immediately agree that the ultimate justification requires calculus, and anything else is at best heuristic and of "motivational" value. (PS: see related question here)

You’re absolutely right. The typical presentations are very fortunate in that the different uses of the term “average” are not contradictory in this setting. I remember bugging my middle school teachers about this exact issue and two out of three of them dismissed my questions as trivial and only one acknowledged the non-triviality.
You know what, let’s say we know the bare definitions of derivatives and integrals, i.e we know the limit of difference quotients and we know the Riemann/Darboux sum definition, and that’s it. Let’s start with a differentiable function $F:[t_1,t_2]\to\Bbb{R}$ and let $f=F’$ be the derivative. Then there are two things we can ask about:

the average rate of change of $F$, defined as $\frac{F(t_2)-F(t_1)}{t_2-t_1}$
the average value of the instantaneous rate of change of $f$, i.e the average value of $f$; this is defined as $\frac{1}{t_2-t_1}\int_{t_1}^{t_2}f(t)\,dt=\frac{1}{t_2-t_1}\int_{t_1}^{t_2}F’(t)\,dt$. Side remark: in case that $f$ is an affine function, one can show that this equals the arithmetic mean of the endpoint values $\frac{f(t_1)+f(t_2)}{2}$… this is also geometrically reasonable so I can sort of get behind giving an a-priori definition of the average value of an affine function as the arithmetic mean at the endpoints.

The picture I have in mind is $F$ for the position and $f$ for the velocity, but I’m phrasing it in general terms to illustrate the non-triviality of the concept. Linguistically, it sounds like these two things should be the same, i.e that
\begin{align}
\frac{F(t_2)-F(t_1)}{t_2-t_1}&=\frac{1}{t_2-t_2}\int_{t_1}^{t_2}F’(t)\,dt.\tag{$*$}
\end{align}
We’re fortunate that they are (under some mild conditions on $f=F’$, such as Riemann-integrability). But do not be fooled, the only reason we know this is because of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. This is a highly non-trivial result (hence why it’s called ‘fundamental’).
Now, even if $f$ is an affine function, still proving the equality of these two things is not easy. You’ll essentially end up re-proving the FTC. Let’s be very concrete and take $f(t)=10t+7$. Now, the following two facts are easy enough to verify:

taking for granted that continuous functions are Riemann-integrable, it is easy enough to prove straight from Riemann sums (using a uniform partition) that for any $t\in [t_1,t_2]$,
\begin{align}
\int_{t_1}^tf(\tau)\,d\tau&=5t^2+7t - \left(5t_1^2+7t_1\right).
\end{align}
For any constant $c$, the function $\Phi_c(t):=5t^2+7t+c$ is differentiable and $\Phi’=f$.

However, these two facts alone say nothing about what $F$ is (besides the implicit fact that $F’=f$). In particular, all we have done is computed an integral of $f$, and we found a whole family of antiderivatives $\Phi_c$ depending on $c$. Proving that $F$ actually equals one of these $\Phi_c$’s (and hence proving the equality $(*)$ above) is non-trivial. The standard proof of the uniqueness up to constants of antiderivatives requires us to apply the mean-value theorem to $F$, which itself relies on the extreme-value theorem for $F$, which again, is intuitive but not trivial to prove because all we know a-priori is that $F$ is a differentiable function on $[t_1,t_2]$ and $F’=f$. Note, all these difficulties arise even though we considered the special case of $f$ being an affine function!
So, notice that even with the knowledge of what derivatives and integrals are, this is still a tough problem. We truly need the FTC in general, or at the very least, the MVT so that we can prove uniqueness of antiderivatives up to constants. Given this, it is of course understandable and in fact necessary that typical presentations perform a sleight of hand and equate the two bullet points above.
